# How to get Plesk to resize partition. Not detecting hardware change

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, vmware, plesk, partition

I have resized the sda2 partition on my Ubuntu Plesk server to give the Plesk install more disk space. I had it on 500Gb and recently increased it to 1Tb (1000Gb) Shown in the image below

[image: Partition Information]

I have attempted to then detect hardware changed within Plesk but it wouldn't work. It is still only showing 500Gb in Plesk (Shown Below). I have used the guide on the Plesk website to try to get this working but it still just shows 500Gb. (https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025636954-Disk-space-is-almost-full-on-Plesk-server-How-to-increase-it-)

[image: Plesk Hard Disk Stats]

I have also used the Advanced monitoring tool and clicked Detect Hardware Changed. But it just shows "No Changes Found"

I am using Plesk Obsidian Version 18.0.30.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to get this detected within Plesk so I can use the full 1000Gb.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not resize the filesystem on that partition after resizing the partition.

You have to resize the filesystem of that partition too:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda2
```